# Nextcloud not connecting to Redis

Tags: php, redis, nextcloud

On a Nextcloud install I am receiving the error

```
No memory cache has been configured. To enhance performance, please configure a memcache, if available. Further information can be found in the documentation.
```

So I have installed APCu, Redis, redis-php and made the required settings in NCs config.php

```
 'memcache.local' => '\OC\Memcache\APCu',
    'memcache.locking' => '\OC\Memcache\Redis',
    'memcache.distributed' => '\OC\Memcache\Redis',
    'filelocking.enabled' => 'true',
    'redis' => 
    array (
      'host' => '127.0.0.1',
      'port' => '6379',
```

When I test the redis connection

```
redis-cli ping
```

I get a

```
PONG
```

(This works both w/ localhost and unix socket)

But Nextcloud obviously does not connect to Redis.

The http user is a member of the redis group.

php-redis module is activated.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The issue was with the location of the above code inside Nextcloud's config.php.
Now it is working as expected.